# SSIS to copy all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, database-migration

I need to copy all databases from server1 to Server2, i saw with SSIS is possible transfer objects with "Transfer SQL Database Task", but it works just for one database.
It's possible coppy all databasses from server1 to server2 using SSIS ?

Best Regards:

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply [backup your database(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql) on the old server?

And after that simply [restore your database(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) in the new server.

However if you want to use SSIS, simply start the TransferDatabaseTask for each database.

Comment: It's because i have more than 20 instances and more than 80 databases in each one. I need to find a automatic solution for each instance.
Thanks for Help

Comment: how are you going to achieve this? If you e.g. program some piece of software with e.g. C# then simply start as many tasks as you need and wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: Im planning to move instance by instance all databases.
Example: Day 1----> Move all databases from Instance 1 to new server instance 1
                Day 2: ----> Move all databases from Instance 2 to new server instance 2

Answer (score 0):

To do this with SSIS I would recommend using [BIML](http://www.bimlscript.com/). If you create a table with all of your mappings in it you can use BIML to iterate over that and create the SSIS packages for you. Or you could create a callable BIML script and repeat over it yourself. BIML is perfect for generating these kinds of repeatable patterns in SSIS.

This [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/125173/) has an intro on how to automate SSIS design patterns. While this is more difficult to use it works really well once you have it done.

[Cathrine Wilhelmsen's blog](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/02/23/dont-repeat-your-biml-callbimlscript-with-parameters/) has some examples on reusing biml as well. This method is much easier to get started with.